# Public IP Address VMWARE Pro 14

Tags: networking, server, vmware-workstation

I am runing linux - VMWARE Workstation Pro 14 
My problem is the following - my public ip is not the same as when I check it online.
For example, if I run ifconfig I will get a public ip such as this:

```
inet 192.168.192.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.192.255
inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feff:9de5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 00:0c:29:ff:9d:e5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 39251  bytes 24563160 (23.4 MiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 29575  bytes 4720544 (4.5 MiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

However this is not my local IP or my Public IP Address.
When I google my public ip address it is completely different and doesn't correspond with the one shown in Linux...

Has anyone had this issue and know how to fix it?

Comment: `192.x.x.x` is the internal IP. `196.x.x.x` in this case is your public IP. You can't change this. https://www.iplocation.net/public-vs-private-ip-address

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))